# Replace duplicate values only in consecutive records with NULL

Tags: sql, oracle

Say I have two tables
Tran (Tran_Id, Tran_Name)
TFlag(Tran_Id, Flag)

My Query Result is Like:

```
TRAN_ID TRAN_NAME   FLAG    
-------------------------
101     Lend        A   
101     Lend        B   
101     Lend        C   
101     Lend        D   
102     Borrow      E   
101     Lend        F   
101     Lend        G
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
TRAN_ID TRAN_NAME   FLAG
-------------------------
101     Lend        A   
(null)  (null)      B   
(null)  (null)      C   
(null)  (null)      D   
102     Borrow      E   
101     Lend        F   
(null)  (null)      G
```

Comment: what have you done so far?and please choose only one RDBMS, its either sql server or oracle.

Comment: In Oracle. I know to replace null for all duplicates. But not for 'only consecutive records'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both SQL Server and Oracle you can use LAG analytic function. Oracle:

```
WITH data (tran_id, tran_name, flag) AS (
    SELECT  01,   'Lend', 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 101,   'Lend', 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 101,   'Lend', 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 101,   'Lend', 'D' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 102, 'Borrow', 'E' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 101,   'Lend', 'F' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 101,   'Lend', 'G' FROM DUAL 
)
SELECT
    NVL2(keep, tran_id, null) tran_id,
    NVL2(keep, tran_name, null) tran_name,
    flag
FROM (
    SELECT
        tran_id, tran_name, flag,
        CASE WHEN LAG(tran_id) OVER (ORDER BY flag) <> tran_id OR LAG(tran_name) OVER (ORDER BY flag) <> tran_name THEN 1 END keep
    FROM
        data)
```

Comment: Its working fine. Thank u. But I have one more scenario.

Comment: IF
Result of my query has fields (domain_name, plan_name, Tran_id,Tranname, flag)
for Every domain_name plan_name is got by joining domain and plan table, tran_id by joining plan and tran table, flag by joining tran and Tflag table...
Here Domain_name and Plan_name has duplicates only continuously. where as tran_id, tran_name,flag has duplicates as in table.. (it may be repeated later)
Now I want the same output as above but records ordered by (domainname, planname, traname)

Answer (score 4):

You could use analytic **LAG() OVER()**.

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6ea33/2)** for a working demo.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT
  2    CASE
  3      WHEN lag(tran_id) over(order by NULL) = tran_id
  4      THEN NULL
  5      ELSE tran_id
  6    END tran_id,
  7    CASE
  8      WHEN lag(tran_name) over(order by NULL) = tran_name
  9      THEN NULL
 10      ELSE tran_name
 11    END tran_name,
 12    flag
 13  FROM t;

   TRAN_ID TRAN_N F
---------- ------ -
       101 Lend   A
                  B
                  C
                  D
       102 Borrow E
       101 Lend   F
                  G

7 rows selected.
```