# remove duplicate column values in sql

Tags: javascript, c#, sql, asp.net

I have the records like this :-

```
1|Share Capital|Subscribed and paid up 
1|Share Capital|Capital Redemption Reverse
1|Share Capital|12% Debertures
1|Share Capital|plant and machinery
1|Share Capital|Shares in SBI
1|Share Capital|Stock in Trade
1|Share Capital|Provisions for taxation
1|Share Capital|Bill Receivable
1|Share Capital|BTPL LOAN
```

i just want to write Share Capital **(2nd column)** at once and **3rd column** as sub records. is there ant query which remove duplicate value and give me output like :-

```
1   Share Capital   Subscribed and paid up 
                    Capital Redemption Reverse
                    12% Debertures
                    plant and machinery
                    Shares in SBI
                    Stock in Trade
                    Provisions for taxation
                    Bill Receivable
                    BTPL LOAN
```

Comment: does your table have a ID column

Comment: I have whole table like this :-                                                                   1 2 1 Share Capital Subscribed and paid up 
2 2 1 Share Capital Capital Redemption Reverse
3 2 1 Share Capital 12% Debertures
4 2 1 Share Capital plant and machinery
5 2 1 Share Capital Shares in SBI
6 2 1 Share Capital Stock in Trade
7 2 1 Share Capital Provisions for taxation
8 2 1 Share Capital Bill Receivable
9 2 1 Share Capital BTPL LOAN

Comment: Is there any Possibilities in coding that i can remove column value of Data table every time?

Comment: @DharaSejpal go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33864227/replace-duplicate-values-only-in-consecutive-records-with-null

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible things that you can do

1. Use a No SQL database like MongoDB. That will allow you to store a BSON document where you can have a list as a column, whereas SQL databases allow only a single value.
2. Normalize the table. This will involve breaking the table into 2 tables and using foreign key reference.

Answer (score 0):

You Can try this

```
select distinct column1 ,column2,
STUFF( (select ' '+CONVERT(varchar,b.column3) from tbl_emp b 
where b.column1 = a.column1  and b.column2 = a.column2 
for xml path('')), 1, 1, '') from table
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select Case when rownumber=1 then Column1 else null end as [Column1],
   Case when rownumber=1 then Column2 else '' end as [Column2],
   Column3
from 
(Select *,Row_number() Over(Partition by Column1 order by Column2) rownumber
 from YourTablename) c
```

Result:

[image]